# how do you populate select list with json data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update html select list with json data as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/84zugx8p/)

```
$("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){


var jsonData=[
    "[{\"id\":1,\"desc\":\"Date\"},{\"id\":2,\"desc\":\"CPU\"}]"
];

var $select = $('#yaxis');
                      $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                      var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
                      $select.append($option);
                    });

                   var $select1 = $('#xaxis');
                      $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                      var $option1 = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
                      $select1.append($option1);
                    });   
});
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your JSON is formatted as a string?  I'm guessing that it's probably coming back that way from a remote service but if you are able to return it as an actual JSON object then it would remove the need to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse to json:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse("[{\"id\":1,\"desc\":\"Date\"},{\"id\":2,\"desc\":\"CPU\"}]");
```

JSFiddle updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/84zugx8p/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.

1) JSON isn't being parsed. jQuery.parseJSON (or a Javascript equivalent) will convert it to a string.

2) You have the entire script running onClick of the submit button. I'm assuming that isn't intended behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/84zugx8p/2/

```
var jsonData=[
    "[{\"id\":1,\"desc\":\"Date\"},{\"id\":2,\"desc\":\"CPU\"}]"
];

jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);

var $select = $('#yaxis');
$(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
    $select.append($option);
});

var $select1 = $('#xaxis');
$(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option1 = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
    $select1.append($option1);
});
```

Unsure if this is just an example, but it is superfluous to include the JSON string and then parse it within the same file. You could just include it as an object/array. See example below:

```
var jsonData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        desc: "Date",
    },{
        id: 2,
        desc: "CPU"
    }
];
```